# Doctrine 2 creating SQLException constraint violation "lastname can't be null" but it's set

Tags: php, pdo, doctrine-orm

I'm not that cocky to believe Doctrine 2 is broken, but I couldn't actually find a perfect title for my case.

So here's the thing:
I have an entity named "Contact" and it's obviously set using Doctrine 2.
So far so good, I'm able to generate my database and all but when it comes to inserting data in it. I've tried to set up some fixtures.php script that allows me to insert data each time I launch my ant script.

Problem is, when I try to use save() I get a PDOException telling me there's a db constraint violation:

```
[exec] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'lastname' cannot be null' in C:\wamp\www\GPos\library\Doctrine\DBAL\Statement.php:131
[exec] Stack trace:
[exec] #0 C:\wamp\www\GPos\library\Doctrine\DBAL\Statement.php(131): PDOStatement->execute(NULL)
[exec] #1 C:\wamp\www\GPos\library\Doctrine\ORM\Persisters\BasicEntityPersister.php(226): Doctrine\DBAL\Statement->execute()
[exec] #2 C:\wamp\www\GPos\library\Doctrine\ORM\UnitOfWork.php(701): Doctrine\ORM\Persisters\BasicEntityPersister->executeInserts()
[exec] #3 C:\wamp\www\GPos\library\Doctrine\ORM\UnitOfWork.php(280): Doctrine\ORM\UnitOfWork->executeInserts(Object(Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\ClassMetadata))
[exec] #4 C:\wamp\www\GPos\library\Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager.php(328): Doctrine\ORM\UnitOfWork->commit()
[exec] #5 C:\wamp\www\GPos\library\GPos\Doctrine\ActiveEntity.php(113): Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager->flush()
[exec] #6 C:\wamp\www\GPos\scripts\fixtures.php(20): GPos_Doctrine_ActiveEntity->save()
[exec] #7 {main}
[exec]   thrown in C:\wamp\www\GPos\library\Doctrine\DBAL\Statement.php online 131
```

That could have been VERY easy to debug if I had forgotten to set 'lastname' property on my entity but it's not the case:

```
$contact_store1 = new GPos_Model_Contact();
$contact_store1->setFirstname('');
$contact_store1->setLastname('Barber'); //Yep, it's here!
$contact_store1->setEmail('gho@zgzg.eu');
$contact_store1->setAdress('Grang 2, Jodone');
$contact_store1->setPhone('0032484555555');
$contact_store1->setCellphone('027512121');
$contact_store1->setTva('21651-1684-15151');
$contact_store1->setDiscount(0.00);
$contact_store1->setType('store');
$contact_store1->setStatus('active');
$contact_store1->save(); //line 19
```

I checked with some echo in ActiveEntity.php and it's set... Have a look at my class maybe that's where everything is going wrong.. :

```
/**
 * @Entity
 * @Table(name="Contact")
 */
class GPos_Model_Contact extends GPos_Doctrine_ActiveEntity {
    /**
     * @Id @Column(type="integer")
     * @GeneratedValue
     */
    private $id;
    /** @Column(length=50) */
    private $lastname;
    /** @Column(length=50) */
    private $firstname;
    /** @Column(length=50, nullable=true) */
    private $email;
    /** @Column(length=150, nullable=true) */
    private $adress;
    /** @Column(length=50, nullable=true) */
    private $phone;
    /** @Column(length=50, nullable=true) */
    private $cellphone;
    /** @Column(length=100, nullable=true) */
    private $tva;
    /** @Column(type="decimal", nullable=true) */
    private $discount;

    /**
     * @ManyToOne(targetEntity="GPos_Model_User")
     * @JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=true)
     **/
    private $user;
    /** @Column(name="type", type="string", columnDefinition="enum('client', 'store_admin', 'user', 'store')")  */
    private $type;
    /** @Column(name="status", type="string", columnDefinition="enum('active', 'deleted')")  */
    private $status;
}
```

So, this is it... Can't really understand why it's happening. Note that I had the same problem with another class that I was trying to set before (I just remembered that) so I guess my problem is more global than that... But if you guys have any clues, that'll be greatly appreciated!

Comment: `$contact_store1->setLastname('Barber'); //Yep, it's here!` have you checked if everything is ok in this method?

Comment: well, it uses ActiveEntity magic setter and I put some echo in it and yep it's set... I really don't understand...

Comment: Make property `$lastname` public and use `var_dump` after `$contact_store1->setLastname('Barber');` if it's null, something is going on there, but I have no idea, what it can be.

Comment: That worked by setting all properties to protected. But I don't really understand why I can't have them private as they use 'private' in doc... http://readthedocs.org/docs/doctrine-orm/en/2.0.x/reference/association-mapping.html. Anyways, make this a proper answer if you want it to be accepted ^^

Comment: I have never had problem like this. I'll try to understand the reason when I have spare time. If I find one, I'll let you know.

Comment: No, everything works fine with me. I'll try your example exactly, maybe there happens some exception.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make property `$lastname` public and use `var_dump` after `$contact_store1->setLastname('Barber');` if it's null, something is going on there, but I have no idea, what it can be.